# Compare rows in a datasource to print specific records

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Master Report uses a DataSource which contains a List(*parentList*) in it.
This List(*parentList*) in turn contains other List(*childList*) in it.
This *childList* is passed as DataSource(*JRBeanCollectionDataSource*) to the SubReport.

This *childList* contains two columns, Below is a tabular format for the list.

```
<pre>TestString  | Date</pre>
<pre> abc | 01JAN12 </pre>
<pre> cdf | 31DEC12 </pre>
<pre> fgh | 08JUN12 </pre>
```

from the above table, dates should be compared to get the "TestString" value of the record with latest date(i.e) **cdf** in this case.

Comparation of the rows or records should be done in the Jasper reports not in a java class.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Is DataSource a SQL table?

Comment: its a JRBeanCollectionDataSource Object

Comment: What is the object inside JRBeanCollectionDS collection? Implement a `comparator` to sort the Objects based on Date in this collection. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the Date String.

Comment: DS contains a list. the list is already passed to the Jasper Report(jrxml). Now, I want to compare the rows in the Jasper Report.
I'm not quite sure but is it possible to use Comparator in the Jasper Report.

Comment: You will need to sort your collection, and them send it to Jasper.

Comment: but the problem is, the collection(List say _childList_) I mentioned in the question is in another Collection(again List say _parentList_).

_ParentList_ is used in the Master Report and _childList_ is passed to the subReport. So, I really don't have any option of sorting the _childList_ before passing it to the jasper.

Or can I sort it in the Master Report. ?

Comment: are you going to display the "TestString" of the latest date in another field inside the report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do it in the java side

Suppose you have the pojo structure

```
public class Parent{
    private List<Child> childList;
    ...
}

public class Child{
    String testString;
    Date date;
}
```

inside the java method that does the report generation

```
...
List<Parent> parent = //method for getting datasource
List<String> testStrings = getTestStrings(parent);
...
//pass the list of testStrings to the report
//inside the report, create a parameter of type List
//pass list.get($V{ctr}) to the subreport where ctr is the current count of the subreport, make it start with 0
```

`getTestStrings` method should do something like

```
private List<String> getTestStrings(List<Parent> parent){
    //loop through parent list
    //pull each child list then do the sort by date then get(0).getTestString()
    //put the value in a list
    //return the list
}
```

Comment: Thank you @onepotato :)

I will try this. I was just wondering if we can do this in Jasper Reports.(Sorting and Stuff)

Comment: Nope, jasper reports is only for displaying whatever data you pass them.

Comment: But I heard that using **Variables** in jasper would do the thing.

Comment: Nope, [variables](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-variables) are for calculation purposes only.